# Typescript importing html files as a string (Express)

Tags: typescript, express, import, typing

I'm trying to import an html file with `import template as "./template.html"` as a string in order to provide it to the user through Express's `res.end(template);` function.

I have created an `index.d.ts` file in the root directory of my project with the following inside:

```
declare module '*.html' {
    const value: string;
    export default value;
}
```

It lets me import `template.html` without any issues but when I run the program it says

```
/home/koen/Workspace/xyz/src/template.html:1
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/koen/Workspace/xyz/out/index.js:11:41)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

It's almost as if it's trying to run the html as Javascript or something. Any ideas why this is happening? I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by installing Babel. Thanks to `index.d.ts` typescript knew what type the content would be (String). But it didn't know how to parse it.

In case anyone else if having the same issue:

### 1. **Install babel core and cli**

Run the following command: `npm install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core`

### 2. **Install the Typescript preset**

Babel is going to take over the transpilation of Typescript to Javascript. In order to do this we have to install the `preset-typescript` preset.

Run the following command: `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript`

Now open `babel.config.json` in the root dir of your project (If it doesn't exist, create it) and add the following:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
}
```

### 3. **Prevent tsc from transpiling**

We are not completely getting rid of `tsc` here. We will still use it in order to check types. But as mentioned before, Babel is taking over the transpilation process and we don't want a conflict. Inside of `tsconfig.json`, set `compilerOptions.noEmit` to `true`.

### 4. **Optional: install the `@babel/preset-env` preset**

If you are planning on using ES2015+ syntax, you have to install this syntax. The process is the same as in step 2.

### 5. **Install babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string**

Oh boy... Yes. I know it's a long name. This is a Babel plugin that will let us import html files.

Run the command: `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string`

Open the `.babelrc` file in the root dir of your project (Once again, if it doesn't exist, create it) and add the following:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "transform-html-import-to-string"
    ]
}
```

### 6. **Add a script to package.json to build and run the application**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && babel src --out-dir lib --extensions '.ts,.tsx' && node lib/index.js"
}
```

tsc will make sure that all the typing is correct, babel will take over the transpilation part.